# create conditions in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I trying to create the conditions of my search, but I have some troubles.

This is the method I'm trying to create.

```
def self.searchadv(title, place, category, date)
    !title.blank? ? conditions = ['title LIKE ?', "%#{title}%"] : conditions = []
    if conditions
        !place.blank? ? conditions << [' AND place LIKE ?', "%#{place}%"] :  conditions << []
        !place.blank? ? conditions << [' AND category LIKE ?', "%#{place}%"] :  conditions << []
        !place.blank? ? conditions << [' AND date LIKE ?', "%#{place}%"] :  conditions << []
    else 
        !place.blank? ? conditions << [' place LIKE ?', "%#{place}%"] :  conditions << []
        !place.blank? ? conditions << [' category LIKE ?', "%#{place}%"] :  conditions << []
        !place.blank? ? conditions << [' date LIKE ?', "%#{place}%"] :  conditions << []
    end
    find(:all, :conditions => conditions)
end
```

It works, greate until I try to append the place parameter and I get this error

> wrong number of bind variables (4 for 1) in: title LIKE ?

if I delete this:

```
if conditions
    !place.blank? ? conditions << [' AND place LIKE ?', "%#{place}%"] :  conditions << []
    !place.blank? ? conditions << [' AND category LIKE ?', "%#{place}%"] :  conditions << []
    !place.blank? ? conditions << [' AND date LIKE ?', "%#{place}%"] :  conditions << []
else 
    !place.blank? ? conditions << [' place LIKE ?', "%#{place}%"] :  conditions << []
    !place.blank? ? conditions << [' category LIKE ?', "%#{place}%"] :  conditions << []
    !place.blank? ? conditions << [' date LIKE ?', "%#{place}%"] :  conditions << []
end
```

Everything works great, but I need this other options in order to create my search and I don't undertand why the error is in the "LiKE"

Does anyone could help me please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is exceptionally ugly, hard to read/debug, and thus prone to error

```
def self.searchadv(title, place, category, date)
  conditions              = {}
  conditions[:title]      = "%#{title}%" if title.present?

  if place.present?
    conditions[:place]    = "%#{place}%"
    conditions[:category] = "%#{category}%"
    conditions[:date]     = "%#{date}%"
  end

  where(conditions)
end
```

**Edit** As OP pointed out, the above doesn't allow for wildcard matches. The following uses ARel's `matches` method to accomplish this.

```
def self.searchadv(title, place, category, date)
  offers     = self.arel_table
  predicates = []

  predicates << offers[:title].matches("%#{title}%") if title.present?

  if place.present?
    predicates << offers[:place].matches("%#{place}%")
    predicates << offers[:category].matches("%#{category}%")
    predicates << offers[:date].matches("%#{date}%")
  end

  if predicates.size > 1
    first = predicates.shift
    conditions = Arel::Nodes::Grouping.new(predicates.inject(first) {|memo, expr| Arel::Nodes::And.new(memo, expr)})
  else
    conditions = predicates.first
  end

  where(conditions).to_a
end
```

Comment: Thanks broth, this is my first rails program I'm sorry for the awful code. Definitely your code is very clean, but I don't any result using your code.

Comment: You have to put `.to_a` on the end of the `where(...)` if you're expecting a result set to be returned instead of an `ActiveRecord::Relation` instance.

Comment: Deefour, I have the following problem here is the query generated using your code: SELECT "offers".* FROM "offers" WHERE "offers"."title" = 'Prueba'

But I need it with a LIKE in the where SELECT "offers".* FROM "offers" WHERE (title LIKE '%Prueba%')

Comment: Sorry for the trouble! I've updated my answer to work with `LIKE` matches using Rail's ARel.

Comment: Thanks Deefour, without your help I never have done this search

Answer (score 0):

I was first trying to keep your code and only try to correct it, but there were to much bad things :) Here is how I would have done it keeping the same structure as you are using (**BUT perhaps it's better to use a conditions Hash as in @Deefour's suggestion**):

```
def self.searchadv(title, place, category, date)
  cond_ary = []
  cond_values = []
  unless title.blank?
    cond_ary << 'title LIKE ?'
    cond_values << "%#{title}%"
  end
  unless place.blank?
    cond_ary << 'place LIKE ? AND category LIKE ? AND date LIKE ?'
    cond_values.push("%#{place}%", "%#{place}%", "%#{place}%")
  end
  conditions = [ cond_ary.join(' AND ') ] + cond_values
  find(:all, :conditions => conditions)
end
```

May I suggest that you study how a conditions array should look like, and then in a ruby console play around with an Array. E.g. see what happens with the array with e.g. `ary << 1`, `ary << [1,2,3]`, `ary.concat([1,2,3])`, `ary.push(1,2,3)` etc.

And when you do

```
expr ? x = 1 : x = 2
```

It's better to use

```
x = expr ? 1 : 2
```

Comment: Thanks 244an, I know my code is very ugly, but I'm just learning I try your code and works fine. But I use Deefour's code. Thanks again for your help